# Are original askers informed when a question is migrated to TeX S.E. ?

Tags: discussion, migration

In view of this recent meta-[question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/221-unanswered-questions), I wonder what was exactly the process when questions were migrated from other S.E. sites to this one when they concerned TeX or LaTeX. I unfortunately was not part of the original followers and committers of the TeX S.E. Sorry if this sounds naïve.

-a- Were the original askers informed about this migration?

-b- Were there creation of new users in TeX S.E. from the original askers' accounts so that they own the original question?

-c- if b) were the users notified?

-d- if b) Was there migration of their email notification preferences?

-e- What happened to the original questions on the original S.E. site? Closed? Deleted?

Answer (score 6):

a) Yes, see [this post on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29344/notify-author-when-question-is-migrated/79450#79450).

b) Yes a new user is created and linked to the account of the old user who stays the owner of the question (possibly this only happens once the user logs in to TeX.SX).

e) It is closed and gets a `[migrated]` appended to the title and anybody who clicks on the title in the questions list will get redirected to the new question (technically anyone who goes to the URL of the old question is redirected).

More details can probably be found somewhere on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).