# Adding the "accepted" mark to a question or to a comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepting, unanswered-questions

Related to [How to end the unanswered status of really solved questions in the comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/how-to-end-the-unanswered-status-of-really-solved-questions-in-the-comments)

There are a lot of question in the main `TeX.SE` like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124050/importing-mat-file-to-pgfplots) with no real answer but with a comment that contains the answer. I would like to know your opinion about three different action for this type of situation:

1. Create an answer with the same answer of the comment, often of 1-2 lines
2. Add the possibility for the user that create the question of marking the question as answered with the usual green symbol (no rep assigned to no one)
3. Add the possibility for the user that create the question of marking the comment as accepted with the usual green symbol (rep to who post the comment or to no one, I don't know)

Comment: Ah shoot. I'm on it :P There is also this [Why do people answer in comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments)

Comment: May be one can comment to the @person-who-suggested-correct-comment to convert his comment to answer and wait for a while. Incase no response, post the comment as community wiki answer to remove from `unanswered` list.

Comment: 2 and 3 would require system changes from stackexchange so not really a meta.tex issue.  otherwise, as texenthusiast said: ping the original commenter with `@` or make it a cw answer.

Comment: @texenthusiast Convert your comment to answer! ;-)

Answer (score 12):

As per Paul Gaborit comment:

Some people might prefer answering in comments, Refer [why do people answer in comments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments) for more reasons.

Hence one can comment to the @person-who-suggested-correct-comment to convert his comment to answer and wait for a while. Incase of no response, post the comment as community wiki answer to remove from unanswered list

As per David Carlisle's Comment:

2 and 3 options would require system changes from stackexchange so not really a meta.tex.sx issue.

Comment: Let's do those system changes! I'm newbie and there are very little questions I can answer, but when I find one it is (almost always) already answered in a comment, I would like this kind of question not to be present in the UNanswered list (otherwise I'll have to return to my thesis writing instead of having fun on TEX SE).