# What are the “TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange guidelines” - closing questions

Tags: discussion, guidelines

My question ([Fonts appear in different sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574112)) gets close-votes because it "has been resolved"

I thought that this is exactly the purpose of this site.

Which guidelines did I violate to get the question closed?

I know that this is not a "good" question in the terms that it is very vague, but Marcel has guessed the correct answer that has helped me. And it might help other people in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The close votes and the reason (already resolved in comments) are not a flaw of the question.

*Sometimes* it may be ok to close a question with that reason (such if the solution comment refers to a simple typo or an outdated TeX installation), the fact that the solution was decided to be posted as a comment instead of being an answer may indicate it.

But, like here, sometimes a solution is just an unconfirmed guess and so posted as a comment. At occasions like this, it's good to

1. ping the comment writer and ask him to turn the comment into an
   answer
2. or post an answer with the solution, with attribution to the
   comment writer (and then choosing community wiki status is common, to not earn reputation for just copying the solution into an answer)

The review queue process, that includes badges rewards for reviewers, unfortunately speeds up voting so 1. can be slower than getting close votes coming in. Note, your question also got 3 "keep open" votes in the review process.

You did good as you did 2. and posted the solution as the answer and accepted it. An improvement would be adding attribution to Marcel, then all is well documented and we can clean up the comments so the solution is clearly visible without distractions.

We had such questions already here, so here are earlier discussions on that topic:

- [Should a question that is answered in a comment be voted on to be closed?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6156/should-a-question-that-is-answered-in-a-comment-be-voted-on-to-be-closed)
- [How to end the “unanswered” status of really solved questions in the comments](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/how-to-end-the-unanswered-status-of-really-solved-questions-in-the-comments)

Comment: Thank you. I believe the answer https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3643 is what I am in need of. I don't see much value of turning manually a comment into an answer in case  it is obviously the correct solution to a problem. If someone in the future comes to this question, there will be no doubt which was the correct way to handle the problem. (Just my two cents, I'll be happy to follow the community guidelines)

Comment: @topskip The advantage of turning a comment into an answer (and accepting it) is that it will prevent the post from being deleted by the roomba. This will ensure that future users with the same problem will still be able benefit from the solution.