# Allegedly unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, unanswered-questions

There are currently more than 3200 questions on tex.sx that have no upvoted answers.  Many of these have been answered, though, often in the comments.

Is it somehow possible to mark a question as answered even though there is not a formal answer?

This issue (or a variation thereof) has already been brought up when the count was at 
[221](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/221-unanswered-questions) and [1408](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/how-to-end-the-unanswered-status-of-really-solved-questions-in-the-comments), but nothing helpful has happened since.

Comment: related reading; [(1)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments) ,[(2)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/what-if-a-comment-answers-a-question), [(3)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/adding-the-accepted-mark-to-a-question-or-to-a-comment)

Comment: If you find questions with answers in comments, the usual procedure is to comment yourself asking for 'conversion', and if that doesn't happen to post a CW answer. However, most of the unanswered questions don't fall into this category in my experience.

Comment: I my opinion (perhaps due to my individual perception) a lot of answers are not upvoted because they belong to duplicate questions and therefore drop out of interest. Another issue is that (good) answers are not upvoted because the OP lost interest or does not care about a real participation, so other users do not upvote due to 'The answer is not accepted, so it can not be a good one, I rather retreat from voting'